# Delete Document with empty document id - elasticsearch TCP client

Tags: elasticsearch, tcp

I am using `TCP client` to perform `delete` operation.
sample code:

```
DeleteRequestBuilder builder = client.prepareDelete(indexName, indexType,indexDocumentId);

ListenableActionFuture<DeleteResponse> deleteResponse =   builder.setOperationThreaded(false).execute();

deleteResponse.actionGet(ESTemplateHelper.INDEX_STATE_ACK_TIMEOUT);
deleteStatus = deleteResponse.isDone();
```

I am passing empty  value/"" to `indexDocumentId`.

`deleteStatus` is always true for empty documentId. But document is not deleted. am i missing something? Isn't it expected to throw any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prepareDelete command is for deleting a single document by its ID. For more information: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/1.7/delete.html

Now, the ID of a document cannot be empty string. So, there should be no such document. The reason `deleteStatus` is true because it holds the value "whether the request is done or not?" and not "was the document deleted?". If you drill down the response, I believe you will find: `found = false`.

In case, you are passing an empty string in the hope of deleting all the documents of type `indexType` in the index `indexName`, then prepareDelete is not the right API for that.

Maybe, you can execute a query on all documents in your type, and delete them one by one. There is also delete by query API but it has been deprecated in 1.5 and removed in 2.0 because it can potentially cause OOM errors. More details here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/docs-delete-by-query.html

In case, you don't care about this index altogether, then deleting the index is the quickest and cleanest way to go: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/indices-delete-index.html. I believe in the similar fashion you can delete your type too.
Eg: `curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/indexName/indexType`

Comment: Is there any way i can delete documents with list of ids?

Comment: It can be done so by using delete by query, but then again it is deprecated and hence not advised. If you want to delete all document in a type, then I will suggest delete the type, then just the type definition with its mapping.
If you want to delete specific documents only, then deleting them one by one will be better, because bulk updates are not atomic operation. There is no concept of transactions in ElasticSearch so nothing like a rollback. In my opinion, if you are carrying out a modification of data, then carry it out via atomic operations only.